# Calculating the runtime of a hash insertion?

Tags: c++, hash, runtime

I need to calculated the runtime of a hash insertion. i have been using clock to do the time but i keep ending up with zero. Is there any certain way that would be the most efficient?

This is my code for it so far:

```
cout << "Testing chaining probing...\n";
    HashTable_chaining ChainingHT( ITEM_NOT_FOUND, 101 );
    int i = 0;
    while(i != DataArray.size())
    {
        clock_t tStart = clock();
        ChainingHT.insert(DataArray[i]);
        cout<<"Time taken:"<<(double)(clock() - tStart)/100000<<endl;
        if(i != NULL)
        {
            collision_count++;
        }
        i++;

    }
```

Comment: Divide by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` not 100000.

Comment: @user977154: It's what you divide the result of `clock()` by to get seconds. On some systems it's 100000. On other systems, it isn't.

Comment: oh its pre defined, do u have any other suggestions? or do u think my clock is good?

Answer (score 3):

a single hash insert is too quick to be measured. Put

```
 clock_t tstart = clock();
```

at the start of your program, doing a **million of insertions**, and

```
 clock_t tend = clock();
```

at the end. Then compute in floating point:

```
 cout << "cpu time=" 
      << ((double)tend - (double)tstart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
```

Typical *current computers do several **billions** elementary machine instructions per second* (but with a clock resolution in milliseconds at best).

Answer (score 1):

My first guess it that insert is extremely fast so you get zeroes... I would never do what you try in this code. Instead I would make, say 10000 insertions, and then calculate how long it takes, and divide that number with 10000 to get average time it takes for insert.

Answer (score 0):

running a 10000 / 100000 / 1000000 insertion loop is ok (you need to play with the number of insertion until you get a value that doesn't take for ever to run).

If you are working in windows, consider using [performance counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter) to getter a much better resolution (see code inside).

Comment: But this solution is not cross-platform (it's win api call).

Comment: true. OP didn't say if he needs cross platform, or not. I am guessing he is working on windows.

Comment: On linux, `clock_gettime` usually gives better precision, and there are some low level tricks for direct performance counter access.