# Why do my function timers keep giving zero as output?

Tags: c++, hash, runtime, clock

I keep getting zero as my time. I need to calculate the total time and the average time for searching though the hash table. Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
void HashTable_chaining::SearchChainingHT(vector<string> QueryArray)
{
    clock_t start, stop, time = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(i != QueryArray.size())
    {
        start = clock();
        find(QueryArray[i]);
        stop = clock();
        time += stop - start;
        i++;
    }
    time = (double)(time/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000;
    cout << "\nThe total time for Search Chaining was " << time << "\nThe average time was " << time/QueryArray.size();
}
```

Comment: Since `time` is a standard function declared in `<time.h>` (or `<ctime>`), I wouldn't give a local variable the same name.  It probably doesn't matter in this case, but it could be confusing to a reader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing integer division:

```
(double)(time/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000;
```

you want the cast inside the `()` instead:

```
((double)time/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000;
```

Furthermore, I'm not sure why you are assigning it back to `time` since that's an integer variable. If you wanted it in milliseconds, you might want to make it explicit:

```
cout << "\nThe total time for Search Chaining was " << time << "  (milliseconds)" << ...
```

**EDIT :**

I overlooked this initially (because of the horizontal scrolling), but you also have integer division here at the end of the printing line:

```
.. << "\nThe average time was " << time/QueryArray.size();
```

You may want to cast that one to `double` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Mysticial answers your question, but I'd like to recommend not using `clock()` at all. If you're compiler supports C++11 there's a better option, `#include <chrono>`.

```
#include <chrono>

void HashTable_chaining::SearchChainingHT(vector<string> QueryArray)
{

    typedef std::chrono::steady_clock Clock;

    Clock::duration total_time = Clock::duration::zero();
    int i = 0;
    while(i != QueryArray.size())
    {
        Clock::time_point start = Clock::now();
        find(QueryArray[i]);
        total_time += Clock::now() - start;
        i++;
    }
    typedef std::chrono::duration<double,std::micro> microseconds;
    typedef std::chrono::duration<double,std::nano> nanoseconds;
    cout << "\nThe total time for Search Chaining was " << microseconds(total_time).count() << " microseconds.\n";
    cout << "The average time was " << nanoseconds(total_time/(double)QueryArray.size()).count() << " nanoseconds.\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366657/calculating-the-runtime-of-a-hash-insertion/8366907#comment10325273_8366907), and my answer there applies here (don't count one operation, but a million of them).