# How to calculate ANSI C code performance?

Tags: c++, c, profiling

I have written a simple code in ANSI C and now would want to perform some measurements.

I have measured execution time (using `clock()` function under the Windows OS and `clock_gettime()` under the Linux OS).

Now I would want to calculate, how many IPSes (Instructions Per Second) my CPU executes, while running this code of mine. (Yes, I know that MIPS is a pathetic parameter, but even this, I want to calculate it)

It would be also nice to see, how many CPIs (Cycles Per Instruction) it takes to perform e.g. addition of 3 elements and others operations I perform.
Google says how to calculate number of MIPS using calculator, some knowledge about my CPU (its clock speed), simple math and a bunch of other parameters (like CPI), but doesn't say HOW to obtain those!

I haven't found also any C/C++ function which would return the number of clock cycles needed to perform e.g. access to a local variable.
There is also a problem to find a Reference Manual by Intel/AMD for a modern CPU, which would have information about opcodes and others.

I have manually calculated, that my ANSI C code takes 37 operations, but those are ANSI C operations, not CPU instructions.

Comment: Have you looked at the "Related"-list on the right?

Comment: @phresnel - a lot of those are for the MIPS processor, which sine the OP mentions Windows I assume they aren't using. Gzegorz - you might want to remove the MIPS tag

Comment: The reason that those things aren't listed anywhere is because they're variable.  The "number of clock cycles required to access a local variable" is somewhere between 0.3 nanoseconds, and 15 seconds, and change without warning.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of getting high accuracy timing on windows is PerformanceCounter, see  [How to use QueryPerformanceCounter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter)
Then you simply need some functions that perform the operations you are interested in timing.  You have to be a little careful of caching etc. so run the calculation several times and look at the distribution of times