# QueryPerformanceCounter run-time error

Tags: c++, performancecounter

Hey im using QueryPerformanceCounter to count how long the function takes in milli-seconds but i am getting this run-time error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around variable 'time1' is corrupted.
```

Ive searched and tried everything and i cannot figure out this error.  Can anybody help me?
Here is the code where it happens:7

```
void print()
{
    unsigned long int time1 = 0;
    unsigned long int time2 = 0;
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&time1);
    //Loop through the elements in the array.
    for(int index = 0; index < num_elements; index++)
    {
        //Print out the array index and the arrays elements.
        cout <<"Index: " << index << "\tElement: " << m_array[index]<<endl;
    }
    //Prints out the number of elements and the size of the array.
    cout<< "\nNumber of elements: " << num_elements;
    cout<< "\nSize of the array: " << size << "\n";

    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&time2);
    cout << "\nTime Taken : " << time1 - time2 <<endl;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use QueryPerformanceCounter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here `QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&time1);`

Do not use `unsigned long int` when passing its address to `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

`unsigned long int` only guarantees at least 32 bits.

Use a 64 bit variable

```
#include <cstdint>    // + include this
int64_t
```

or

```
long long int
```

Comment: @Becca Try using long long int. I don't see any other problem in this code.

Comment: Sorry that was my fault i forgot an &.  I am getting a minus number though for the time :S.

Comment: Why the casting? Using `LARGE_INTEGER time1, time2;` would make it all a lot easier.

Comment: @BoPersson I like to know what the heck my variables actually are, especially when LARGE_INTEGER is only used in QueryPerformanceCounter().