# C++ Something that equivalent with System.DateTime.Now.Ticks?

Tags: c++

I am just develop the game in C# and I was migrated C++ newly, I just want to rewrite the game into C++, and almost successfully to translate of all the code from C# to C++, but there are some problem, my game use System.DateTime.Now.Ticks in C#... and I was stuck

so.. there are something equivalent with System.DateTime.Now.Ticks in C++?

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: I want the game running in Cross-Platform...
but I am using Windows

Comment: [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter) already in StackOverflow -- does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### look at **this** [tutorial on cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) to get platform independent.

Function `Clock()` returns the amount of tics that this process have consumed. To access this function, you need to include: `#include <time.h>`.

To get the same thing, only in seconds, you can use the `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` macro, so you can do: `Clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to get the number of seconds that this process took. But remember that you might loose some precision this way.

---

You might not need this exact functionality though... If you are looking for the exact time that has elapsed since the program has started, you (as far as I can remember) must use [`difftime()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/) function. You might be loosing some precision if you need exact tics, depending on your platform.

This way you must save the current time at the beginning of your application, and subtract it from the current time during the application.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

time_t programstart;

int main ()
{
  time(&programstart); //assign the current time 

  /*... the program ...*/

  //get seconds since start
  double secondssincestart = difftime(time(NULL), programstart);

  printf ("the program took: %f seconds\n", secondssincestart);

  return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Since this post still gets some attention, it is important to note, that today's C++11 has standard, easy to use, and pretty handy library [`chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono).

Comment: You probably need to edit that code - where's the declaration of `now` and `seconds`?

Comment: @TobySpeight - right, it was just a hasty edit of linked example... Now it actually works :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime`. Like `DateTime.Ticks`, each tick of `QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime` is also 100-nanosecond. If you need higher resolution, you need to go for `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee662306(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't know how to use it :\ MSDN doesn't provide the usage

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an equivalent class or method, but you can do this:

```
SYSTEMTIME systemTime;
GetLocalTime(&systemTime);

FILETIME fileTime;
SystemTimeToFileTime(&systemTime, &fileTime);

ULARGE_INTEGER largeInteger;
largeInteger.LowPart = fileTime.dwLowDateTime;
largeInteger.HighPart = fileTime.dwHighDateTime;

ULONGLONG ticks = reinterpret_cast<ULONGLONG&>(largeInteger);
```

Comment: It almost... but the last 4 digit always give me 0000 << I am still need this

Answer (score 0):

In Windows with MFC the Ticks equivalent to System.DateTime.Now.Ticks

```
ULONGLONG GetTicksNow()
{
    COleDateTime epoch(100, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00);
    COleDateTime currTime = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();
    COleDateTimeSpan span = currTime - epoch;
    CTimeSpan cSpan(span.GetDays(), span.GetHours(), span.GetMinutes(), 
                                                       span.GetSeconds());
    ULONGLONG diff = cSpan.GetTotalSeconds();
    LONG missingDays = 365 * 99 + 24;
    CTimeSpan centSpan(missingDays, 0, 0, 0);
    ULONGLONG centSeconds = centSpan.GetTotalSeconds();// *1000000000;//
    ULONGLONG totSec = (diff + centSeconds)*10000000;
    return totSec ;
}
```