# C++ calculate Row major and Column major access time

Tags: c++, c

I want to calculate access time for these two ways : Row major and Column major
as we know C/C++ is Row major , so when we process in first way (Row major) we should be faster.
but look at this code in C++ language

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdio>
clock_t RowMajor()
{
char* buf =new char [20000,20000];
clock_t start = clock();
for (int  i = 0; i < 20000; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j <20000; j++) 
        {
         ++buf[i,j];
        } 
    clock_t elapsed = clock() - start;
   delete [] buf;
return elapsed  ;
} 
clock_t ColumnMajor()
 {
char* buf =new char[20000,20000];
clock_t start = clock();
for (int  i = 0; i < 20000; i++) 
    for (int  j = 0; j < 20000; j++) 
    {
        ++buf[j,i]; 
    }
clock_t elapsed = clock() - start;
 delete [] buf;
return elapsed ;
```

}

```
 int main()
  {     
        std::cout << "Process Started." << std::endl;
        printf( "ColumnMajor took  %lu microSeconds. \n",   ColumnMajor()*1000000/ (CLOCKS_PER_SEC)  );
        printf( "RowMajor took  %lu microSeconds. \n",  RowMajor() *1000000/ (CLOCKS_PER_SEC) );
        std::cout << "done" << std::endl; return 0; 
  }
```

but whenever i run this code i get diffrent answers , sometimes Rowmajor time is grater than column major time and sometimes is opposite,
any help is apriciated.

Comment: `buf[i,j]` is not doing what you think it is doing. It's actually equivalent to `buf[j]`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator In your case both traversals do exactly the same thing.

Comment: What are your optimization settings? Since buf is never read, the compiler might completely optimize the code away

Comment: ++buf[i][j] make error

Comment: The time is fluctuating because `clock()` is not precise enough for a measurement like this. Run your micro-benchmark 10,000 times to get some sense of what's going on.

Comment: How can i access optimazation settings?

Comment: To make this actually show anything useful you need to size your rows properly to use the entire cache line in your processor. I'm guessing your row cache in your processor isn't 20000... Otherwise I don't get what you're trying to show, it's pointless because different accesses you think are across column and row borders aren't because a 2D array in C/C++ is actually a 1D array followed by other 1D arrays.

Comment: How do i run my micro benchmark?

Comment: Before you start optimization, look at Raxvans comment. Your ColMajor and RowMajor code is the same

Comment: `new char [20000,20000]` is a code obfuscation technique I wasn't aware of. Too bad that VC spoils the fun on /W4 and says "warning C4709: comma operator within array index expression" :)

Answer (score 3):

in c++ the [coma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) can't be used create/access matrix thing. To make a `matrix` you need to keep track of `with` and `height` and allocate all the memory as an array. Basically you need to create a vector with the number or elements equivalent to number of elements in the matrix and you get each element by taking the `x + y * width`.

```
clock_t RowMajor()
{
    int width = 20000;
    int height = 20000;
    char* buf = new char[width * height];
    clock_t start = clock();
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            ++buf[i + width * j];
        }
    clock_t elapsed = clock() - start;
    delete[] buf;
    return elapsed;
}
```

for `ColumnMajor` the `buf` needs to be accessed with `buf[j * width + i];`

An alternative way to create a matrix (from comments, thanks to  James Kanze) is to create the buffer like so: `char (*buf)[20000] = new char[20000][200000]`. In this case, accessing the buffer is like: `buf[i][j]`

The safest way to do this is to use std::vector or array, and avoid using new/delete. Use std::vector to prevent buffer write overflows:

```
clock_t RowMajor()
{
    int width = 20000;
    int height = 20000;
    std::vector<char> buf;
    buf.resize(width * height);
    clock_t start = clock();
    for (int j = 0; j <height; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i <width; i++)
        {
            ++buf[i + j * width];
        }
    clock_t elapsed = clock() - start;
    return elapsed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , Result :
Process Started.
ColumnMajor took  4292953329 microSeconds.
RowMajor took  4293525493 microSeconds.
done
it makes no sense

Comment: He can write: `char (*buf)[20000] = new char[20000][200000]`, and then use it.  (Personally, it's not something that I'd want in production code, but it could be justified for benchmarking low level operations.)

Comment: Size your rows to be your CPU cache row size for the results to be meaningful.

Comment: @user3365425 i made a small mistake, i corrected the code.`RowMajor` was actually `ColumnMajor`

Comment: Thank you , but why does it still give wrong answer? 
Process Started.
ColumnMajor took  1745196 microSeconds.
RowMajor took  4293016329 microSeconds.
done

Comment: every time i run the code , i give diffrent answers
Process Started.
Process Started.
ColumnMajor took  4293807493 microSeconds.
RowMajor took  4292860329 microSeconds.
done

Comment: @user3365425 something is not right with the time calculated: 4293016329 microSeconds is abous 1192 hours.

Comment: yes , i think so , but it seems be ok , Clocks_per_second give seconds , multiple by 1000000 giv micro seconds

Comment: yes , i think so , but it seems be ok , Clocks_per_second give seconds , multiple by 1000000 giv micro seconds

Comment: @user3365425 use `QueryPerformanceCount` it's a better solution for measuring small time intervals http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter

Comment: The second fn you privided makes some errors about vector ...
I'm a PHP man and not very good at C++ , Can you explain QueryPerformanceCount more?

Comment: with QueryPerformanceCount : 
Process Started.
ColumnMajor took  2578283148  .
RowMajor took  3031780920  .
done ,
still wrong answer :(

Comment: @user3365425 something else must be broken in the code , On my small test i got `ColumnMajor` to be 10 time slowe. I used QueryPerformanceCount and the 5000x5000 elements initialized with 0;

Comment: Beware of CPU cache hits and misses.  Search the web for "data cache hits misses".  This may account for variances in your timings.

Comment: i think the problem is about converting time , calc= ColumnMajor() /CLOCKS_PER_SEC  ; works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Raxvan ,this is the final code works fine so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>

int calc = 0;


clock_t RowMajor()
{
int width = 20000;
int height = 20000;
char* buf = new char[width * height];
clock_t start = clock();
for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        ++buf[i + width * j];
    }
clock_t elapsed = clock() - start;
delete[] buf;
return elapsed;
}
clock_t ColumnMajor()
{
 int width = 20000;
int height = 20000;
char* buf = new char[width * height];
clock_t start = clock();
for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        ++buf[j + width * i];
    }
clock_t elapsed = clock() - start;
delete[] buf;
return elapsed;
}




 int main()
  {     
        std::cout << "Process Started." << std::endl;
        calc= ColumnMajor() /CLOCKS_PER_SEC  ;
        printf( "ColumnMajor took  %lu  . \n",  calc );
        calc=RowMajor()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
        printf( "RowMajor took  %lu  . \n", calc );
        std::cout << "done" << std::endl; return 0; 
  }
```