# how to measure time?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, benchmarking

I know there are many topics for finding elapse time of a code and I have read many, but i really get confused I decided to use high resolution clock and ran this code to see how many times a second the clock ticks

```
cout << chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den << endl;
output:10000000
```

and then I defined the begin time and the end time as below

```
int main()
{
    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    .
    .
    .
    .
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout<<"RUN TIME IS :"<<endl;
    std::cout << std::chrono:: duration_cast <chrono:: nanoseconds>(end-begin).count() << "ns" << std::endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    //**********************************************************
    return 0;
}
```

but most of the time the output is 0, but the code is more than 2000lines I waste a lot of time,but the problem has not solved yet . So please let me know is it a good way to determine the elapse time ? And what is the wrong with my code ? I am using VS2012
another question is that i want to measure a computation time of a problem and I am not sure which one should i measure(system time , user time or real time) ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: This question is really urgent and I am not advance in c++ please guide me with your clear answers.

Comment: I can't be sure what you're asking. What you've shown [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/345b7d36dab164f5).

Comment: I have omitted the main part of the code and the mentioned part is timing section, I asked for benchmarking and measuring computation time should I use high resolution clock ? and the code I prepared comes up with 0, while the code is more than 2000lines ?@chris

Comment: Ah, you deleted your own question for some reason, and then repeated it today. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170412/high-resolution-timer-error

Comment: @IMI:Please read my post on similar topics: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23116709/2724703

Comment: @MatsPetersson yes because I havent found any answer

Comment: See my link above: It's basically that Windows implementation (at least in VS 2012) is "b0rked". There are various other ways to measure time in VS. And I wrote a comment to the original question explaining about system, user and real time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct...  But the clock is not actually required to be "high-resolution", that's implementation defined.

You may consider using an alternate method, which is built into the Windows API:

Check out the QueryPerformanceCounter APIs, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter) question.

Comment: the topic was so useful, but I want to know how can I add an ending point for the timer?

Comment: First, sorry for the wait. Anyways, you don't need to define an ending point.  The timer is normally implemented in hardware; you would calculate elapsed time by calling `QueryPerformanceCounter`, and subtracting the two `QuadParts`, divided by the value returned by `QueryPerformanceFrequency`.  I don't know what you're thinking, but the timer doesn't start at 0, so you must always have an initial  time to determine the difference between them.  Understand?

Comment: Yes, fortunately the problem is solved by your clear answers.
Thank you again