# Why the GetLocalTime(&sys); showed strange result?

Tags: c++, winapi, time

I want to get the local time in real time.The code and result is as follow, it showed strange;

```
int main() {
    while (true) {
        char sentdata[64] = { 0 };
        GetLocalTime(&sys);
        sprintf(sentdata, "A,%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d,B\n", sys.wHour, sys.wMinute, sys.wSecond, sys.wMilliseconds);

        cout << sentdata << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

I tried same code on other PC, the result shown is as following, it can show every millisecond.

[image]

Why the tmie is same in some loop? I think the time should be different every loop.

Comment: Clock updates are synchronous with the clock tick interrupt.  Which fires 64 times per second by default.  1000 / 64 = 15.625, just what you see.  It can be messed with, timeBeginPeriod().

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your comment.But i tried the same code on another pc , i can get every millisecond as the pic i have updated,not 16 milliseconds one update,why?

Comment: I already told you.  Expecting to see every single millisecond pass by is mostly a pipe dream on a multi-tasking operating system.  Although you can technically lock it down to ensure no other processes can get started and troublemaker drivers are disabled so your thread is never pre-empted.  Technically.

Comment: @HansPassant But you can see the pic2 i have upload, i just use the same code on another pc and i can see every millisecond.

Comment: Regarding your second PC, the heartbeat may be increased beyond the typical 64 beats/second rate, but I can't tell you why. See here for further details: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/windows-timer-resolution-megawatts-wasted/

Comment: Starting up Chrome is a pretty good way to get another program to call timeBeginPeriod(1) for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This a typical timing behavior on Windows systems, even with the high-resolution clock: time only increases in jumps of about 16 ms.

For accurate timing on Windows, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33337138/5482150)

Comment: Thank you for your comment,but i try the same code on another pc it can show every milliseconds.Why?

Comment: I have update pic, you can see the result on another pc.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs in nanoseconds, while the output is in milliseconds.