# Find out the time when handle signals

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using **WINAPI**.

```
DWORD dwRc = ::WaitForMultipleObjects(3, aHandles, FALSE, pRedir->m_dwWaitTime);
```

My `aHandles[2]` signals before `pRedir->m_dwWaitTime` runs the required stuff and again runs the instruction:

```
DWORD dwRc = ::WaitForMultipleObjects(3, aHandles, FALSE, pRedir->m_dwWaitTime);
```

and process continues.

I want to modify the value of `m_dwWaitTime`. 
I want to determine the time between the start of `aHandles[2]` and when it signaled.

How do I do that?

Comment: Store current time before starting to wait and after wait returns. Then calculate the difference. Note that wait time supplied to the function is the minimum wait time, in reality it can return after a longer interval.

Comment: how do i get the current time.This function just specifics if there is a timeout or not.

Comment: If you want a winapi solution then you can use `QueryPerformanceCounter`, if a c++ solution then `::std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`.

Comment: @VTT the wait functions operate at millisecond precision, so the performance counter API is overkill when `GetTickCount/64()` would suffice

Comment: @RemyLebeau Even though wait functions take and tick functions return milliseconds typically neither of them operate at millisecond precision.

Comment: I tried using  QueryPerformanceCounter [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter) but i get random timing

Comment: Then most likely you are using it incorrectly. Code at that question seems to be fine.