# How to calculate running time in C language

Tags: c

The following function is not compiling:

```
double GetCurTime()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER CounterFreq;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&CounterFreq);

    LARGE_INTEGER Counter;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&Counter);
    return (double)Counter.QuadPart / (double)CounterFreq.QuadPart;
}
```

The C the compiler I am using does not recognize `LARGE_INTEGER` and  `QueryPerformanceFrequency`.

If anyone recognizes these items, can you please suggest where I might find them?
Perhaps they are in a header file, or a library that I do not currently have.

Comment: So, whats your question?

Comment: There is a very similar question _[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter)_ that has a detailed answer to how to use `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use QueryPerformanceCounter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the `<time.h>` library and use the `time_t time(time_t *timer);` function.

Also, if you want to use QueryPerformanceCounter, then you need to include Winbase.h (and Windows.h).